# Filter cloud watch log insights based on the availability of two or strings in the log and make it case insensitive

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

How to check if two or more predefined words are available in the log case insensitively and filter out those logs only. I am currently using

```
                   FILTER log like /(?i)(alter table)/.
```

This matches only if the words are in same order as the filter, but it is  case insensitive.
Is there a way to do something like

```
                   FILTER any(['alter', 'create', 'drop if exists']) in log
```

along with case insensitivity while filtering.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `or` and `and` statements in filter

```
| filter @message ~="alter" or @message ~= "create"
```

you can also use regex here as well

```
fields @timestamp, message, id, some_other_var
| filter !isempty(some_other_var) and id like /\w*D\b/ # Ends in D
```